# UniversalImageLoader crash (while scrolling wild up and down)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, universal-image-loader

I am having crashes in a gridview using NOSTRAs UniversalImageLoader. There are around 1.5k images in the list to scroll through. But i guess its not related the bitmaps themself in the memory, but its related to too many thread creations. Basically i am scrolling up and down and up and down very wild. And i guess there are too many thread created and i am seeing this in the log very often

```
D/dalvikvm: create interp thread : stack size=32KB
D/dalvikvm: create new thread
D/dalvikvm: new thread created
D/dalvikvm: update thread list
```

and eventually i see

```
E/dalvikvm: Thread creation failed (err=Invalid argument, stacksize=1085584KB)
A/libc: Fatal signal 7 (SIGBUS) at 0x84849142 (code=1), thread 28383 (nomad5.beatsnap)
```

or sometimes this

```
E/dalvikvm: Thread creation failed (err=Invalid argument, stacksize=1085584KB)
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x84849142 (code=2), thread 14546 (nomad5.beatsnap)
```

sometimes is paired with

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: pthread_create (stack size 16384 bytes) failed: Try again
```

but sometimes this crash is not shown in the log. Here is my UIL config

```
.denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory().diskCacheSize(64 * 1024 * 1024).threadPoolSize(5);
```

and here my display options

```
.bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
.imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_INT)
.cacheInMemory(false).cacheOnDisk(true).showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_image_choose_error)
.showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_image_choose_error)
```

I am loading images already in a very small size. Here is the loading call

```
ImageLoader.getInstance()
                   .displayImage("file://" + this.imageList.get(position),
                                 new ImageViewAware(imageView),
                                 this.options,
                                 new ImageSize(100, 100),
                                 new SimpleImageLoadingListener()
                                 {
                                     @Override
                                     public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage)
                                     {
                                     ...
                                     }
                                 },
                                 null);
```

By the way, my apps memory is constantly stable at around 40MB.

[image]

So as you see i disabled all the memory caching. I am also using large heap in the XML.

**Any suggestions how to avoid this crashes? Is there a way to limit the thread creation counts?**

*Update #1*

I have tried it with `loadImage` and removed all other code. Its still happening.

Here is my adapter code. The `imageList` is a list with ~1.5k entries. Just paths to the images on the phone.

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    // all the paths
    private final ArrayList<String> imageList;
    // the layout inflater
    private final LayoutInflater    layoutInflater;
    // checked array
    private final SparseBooleanArray checkedArray = new SparseBooleanArray();
    // options for loading into the grid
    private final DisplayImageOptions               options;

    /**
     * Constructor to use
     */
    public ImageAdapter(@NonNull Context context,
                        @NonNull ArrayList<String> imageList)
    {
        // init members
        this.layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.imageList = imageList;
        // image options
        this.options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                                                        .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_INT)
                                                        .cacheInMemory(false)
                                                        .cacheOnDisk(true)
                                                        .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_image_choose_error)
                                                        .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_image_choose_error)
                                                        .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)
                                                        .build();
    }  

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return this.imageList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        if(convertView == null)
        {
            convertView = this.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image_choose_element, null);
        }
        convertView.setTag(position);            
        // load the image
        final View finalConvertView = convertView;
        ImageLoader.getInstance()
                   .loadImage("file://" + this.imageList.get(position),
                              new ImageSize(100, 100),
                              this.options,
                              null);           
        return convertView;
    }  
}
```

and here is the file `fragment_image_choose_element.xml` that is inflated in the `getView` method:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:id = "@+id/image_choose_element"
    xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity = "center"
    android:gravity = "center">

    <ImageView
        android:id = "@+id/image_choose_element_image"
        android:layout_width = "match_parent"
        android:layout_height = "match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds = "false"
        android:scaleType = "centerCrop"/>    

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try to load an smaller image as crash is caused by OOM.

Comment: already loading with just 100x100.. see edit... its not related during bitmap allocation. its during creating a thread

Comment: The pthread create failure is just an OOM error.  A thread is created with a stack, and it doesn't have sufficient memory to create that stack.

Comment: Actually looking at that first error-  you're trying to allocate a 1GB stack. That's very wrong.  Something got screwed up with a parameter somewhere in the thread creation.  Possibly stack corruption, possibly a weird bug.  Added with a sigbus stack corruption seems possible.

Comment: Hi, did yout try those recomendations https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/wiki/Useful-Info, also enable writeDebugLogs() maybe it will help you detect the problem

Comment: yep... tried all relevant stuff (i dont use downloading, its all coming from SDCARD)

Comment: you used .cacheInMemory(false) and you still have OOM, your app must have a memory leak somewhere. maybe https://github.com/square/leakcanary will help

Comment: mh, as you see in the attached screenshot, there is no memory issue